# How to configure PoEdit to pick up translation string?

Tags: themes, localization

I need to localise Flash theme, but don't know how to configure PoEdit to pick up such string.

Tried: _nx:1,4c (but this picks up only Reply to ..) but does not find Thoughts on ..

```
    printf( /* translators: 1: number of comments, 2: post title */
            _nx(
                    '%1$s Reply to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;',
                    '%1$s Thoughts on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;',
                    $comments_number,
                    'comments title',
                    'flash'
            ),
            number_format_i18n( $comments_number ),
            get_the_title()
    );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `_nx:4c,1,2`. There is BTW a nice repository at github for this kind of problems that has a complete keywords list: [Blank-WordPress.pot](https://github.com/fxbenard/Blank-WordPress-Pot)